# JSON object and array basics: what belongs to the object, and what doesn't?

Tags: json

I'm going through a [JSON tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp). I'm having a hard time understanding the data types.

The linked page says this is an object:

```
{
"employee":{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }
}
```

Then a [few pages later in the same tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), it seems an object is this instead:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }
```

So what am I looking at in the first example? Is that two objects nested inside each other?

Similarly, arrays:

```
{
"employees":[ "John", "Anna", "Peter" ]
}
```

versus

```
[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example `{"employee":{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" }}`, the json represents an object with a single property called `employee`. That property is an object which has three properties `name`, `age` and `city`.

Your second example `{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }` represents an object with three properties `name`, `age` and `car`.

In the example:

```
{
"employees":[ "John", "Anna", "Peter" ]
}
```

`employees` is an array of strings. You could change `employees` to be an array of objects like this:

```
{
"employees": [
  {
    "name":"John", 
    "age":30, 
    "city":"New York" 
  },
  {
    "name":"Mick", 
    "age":30, 
    "city":"London" 
  }
 ]
}
```